# When we don't use 'break' statement in switch statements,why is 'deafult' evaluated before other cases that is below 'default'?

Tags: c

Yesterday I saw the below code. As you can see it hasn't got any `break`  I predicted that it would print "354" because I thought the `default` part would be finally evaluated (after checking all the cases.)

But that isn't practically correct as it printed "345". Can somebody explain the reason?

```
int main ()
    {
        int a = 2;
        switch (2*a-1)
        {
            case 1:  printf ("1");
            case 2:  printf("2");
            case 3:  printf("3");
            default: printf("4");
            case 5:  printf("5");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code is processed in order from top to bottom.  The `case` and `default` labels only indicate where execution should jump to.

Comment: The compiler does not re-order the code and labels. So it starts at 3 and then does default and then 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `2*a-1` is 3, the code jumped to the `case 3` label and kept running from there. The other labels were ignored because no code ever jumped to them. The `default` label is only jumped to if the value in the `switch` doesn't match any of the `case` labels.